# Tensorflow: how should I reshape a row placeholder to a column placeholder

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, tensorflow

I want to convert a row placeholder, e.g., `[1, 2]`, to a column placeholder, e.g., `[[1], [2]]`

```
y = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[None], name='target')
y = tf.reshape(y, (y.shape[0], 1))

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    init.run()
    print(sess.run(y, feed_dict={y:[1,2]}))
```

But I get an error:

```
TypeError: Failed to convert object of type <class 'tuple'> to Tensor. Contents: (Dimension(None), 1). Consider casting elements to a supported type.
```

The problem is the usage of `y.shape[0]`. The dimension of y is defined as `None`. I have also tried `tf.shape(y)`, which does not work as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you meant it, but you *can't* change the shape of a node in tensorflow in runtime. So as `target` is defined as `[?]` placeholder, it'll remain so.

What you can do instead is convert it to a new tensor (which won't be a placeholder!) using `tf.expand_dims` function, as already suggested. This means that you still have to feed in `[?]` array, but you can use the reshaped tensor in computations.

```py
y = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[None], name='target')
z = tf.expand_dims(y, axis=1)  # another tensor

with tf.Session() as sess:
  tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
  print(sess.run(z, feed_dict={y:[1, 2]}))
```

Answer (score -1):

To simply take rows to columns by using tf.expand_dims()

```
y = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[None], name='target')
y = tf.expand_dims(y,axis=1)
```

However, you have another problem in feeding data as simply adding a dimension to the tensor is not going define its shape, its simply going to add an additional index.  This is another question which you can post independently.